# Optional Parent Relation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

**Example:** Some items belong to specific users. The User is the parent, the item is the child. Indexing those items and users can be done by routing the items to the shards of the users.

**Problem:** The majority of items does not belong to a specific user since they have been posted anonymously. I could have those items routed to a parent-id:"anonymous", but that would lead to the majority of items being stored in one single shard.

**Question:** How can I introduce optional parent-child-relations so that items belonging to a registered user route to the users shard, while anonymous items get distributed randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store them in two different indexes and search both.

Here's a video and article that has more on sharding/index partitioning strategies:

- [Sizing Elasticsearch](https://www.found.no/foundation/sizing-elasticsearch/)
- [ElasticSearch: Big Data, Search, and Analytics](https://vimeo.com/44716955)

Comment: should I store them in two diffrent indexes, or just in two diffrent types?

Comment: That should be two different indexes. The type concept actually does not exist in Lucene indexes, which is what an Elasticsearch shard is. More on that here: https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up/